# Import Variable from function in Class

Tags: python, class, oop, flask, import

I can't figure out how to import a variable that is created in a loop in a function and in a Class. I would then have the error " AttributeError: "Example" object has no attribute "address" .

It looks like this:

a.py

```
class Example():
    global address
    address = ""

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def loop_function(self, cam):

        for i in imageZbar.symbols:
            print(i.data)
            address = i.data
        return address
```

b.py

```
from a import Example
from flask import Flask,render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

app.route("/example/")
def blabla():
    imported_address = Example.address
    return render_template("example.html", imported_address = imported_address)
```

Comment: In `b.py`, you could do `imported_address = Example().loop_function()`. Isn't that enough? You don't need to make anything `global`.

Comment: Sorry, loop_function() has actually 2 arguments, I just edited it. When I do like you've described it says 'takes exactly 2 Arguments (1 given).'

Comment: Then just pass that second argument to `loop_function()`. The first argument is `self` which is passed by default.

Comment: If I use Example().loop_function(cam) in b.py I have a NameError 'gloabal name 'cam' is not defined'

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It seems to me you don't need a class `Example` at all

Comment: It is supposed to be a Flask App that streams a camera in the browser and scans Qr codes with Zbar. a.py would be the module that initializes the camera, zbar and Opencv. I'm not exactly sure if a class is then required.

Comment: If you don't need `cam` (I see it isn't being used anywhere) then just pass `None`.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the line `global address`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you put a global when it is behaving like a class member... Why not use:

a.py

```
class Example():

    def __init__(self):
        self.address = ""

    def loop_function(self, cam):
        for i in imageZbar.symbols:
            print(i.data)
            self.address = i.data
        return self.address
```

b.py

```
from a import Example

app = Flask(__name__)
eg = Example()
cam = None # I do not see anywhere this variable
eg.loop(cam)

app.route("/example/")
def blabla():
    return render_template("example.html", imported_address = eg.address)
```

If you do not need it to behave like a class (i.e. only want to use the loop function) why even bother to create a class, why don't you create a function. Also, why it has to be global?

BTW, checking the comments, you have an error of the variable cam... I do not see that you initialize it anywhere in the code

Also, you do not show where are you getting:

```
 imageZbar.symbols
```

this should be a parameter for the loop function as far as I know